# Saving a CSS web font in HTML5 local storage

Tags: html, css, base64, local-storage, webfonts

When building our site, we found that loading web fonts significantly slowed down page rendering on mobiles, so we disabled them on smaller devices. I've since heard you can get around this problem by saving the web font in HTML5 local storage. A friend who works at the Guardian has told me their [mobile site](http://m.guardian.co.uk) saves its font in local storage as a base64 encoded string.

I can understand easily enough how to save the font, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to load it into the browser when I retrieve it. Using Javascript I could append the base64 string into a style tag in the head of my page, but then I'd be adding to the data size of every page when I need to be careful about page weights. Is there a more efficient way I can load the font-face CSS declaration? For example, if it was in a separate CSS file the browser would cache it.

EDIT ---------------------------------------------

I've figured out this example.. If the device has a small screen I check localStorage for the font data. If it doesn't exist in localStorage I do an ajax request, append the data into the head of my page and store it in localStorage. If it does exist, I just append it. Does this look like an efficient way of loading a web font on mobile?

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 481) {
            if (typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
                if (localStorage.getItem('base64fonts') === null) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'fonts-base64.css',
                        success: function(response){
                            $('head').append('<style>' + response + '</style>');
                            localStorage.setItem('base64fonts', response);
                        },
                        dataType: 'text'
                    });
                } else {
                    $('head').append('<style>' + localStorage.getItem('base64fonts') + '</style>');
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: check this out http://www.sencha.com/learn/taking-sencha-touch-apps-offline/

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial may be a good place to start: http://toddmotto.com/storing-data-in-the-browser-with-the-html5-local-storage-api/

Also, any reason you can't just have the browser cache these by adjusting your `.htaccess` file settings?

```
# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
```

source: https://github.com/cferdinandi/htaccess

Browsers automatically download the appropriate font file (that's how `@font-face` works). Setting an expire header will recommend a suggested cache time for the file, preventing re-downloads on each access.

I use this technique on a few sites I've developed, and it dramatically speeds up load time on subsequent visits.

Comment: Thanks Chris, nice tutorial.. and the .htaccess rules are useful. What may not be clear from my example is that I'm mostly hoping to avoid the delay in the appearance of text that tends to happen on mobiles while the device is downloading the font - it takes longer for any text to appear.. or text appears then disappears as the browser re-renders it in the custom font. One solution is to append the stylesheet with the font data only on document load, or to grab it from local storage.

Comment: Won't that happen on the first load regardless of local storage? Either way, the browser needs to download the font first.

Comment: That's right - in my example I'm trying to mitigate the impact of the loading by deferring it till doc ready, though doc load may be better.

Comment: Oh I get it now. I thought you were trying to avoid FOUC. Can you add a delay via JS? I think browsers will get better at handling this on their own over time, too.

Answer (score -1):

The responsive mobile site for the Guardian is available on github.

Here is what they do with local storage for fonts.

[https://github.com/guardian/frontend](https://github.com/guardian/frontend/blob/master/common/app/assets/javascripts/modules/fonts.js#L88)

Comment: If you're interested in the above link but getting a broken link: https://github.com/guardian/frontend/blob/53e6eec5569f14142299288485b1d3f3cb7e9bca/common/app/assets/javascripts/modules/fonts.js